# Is it possible to initialize a data member as const based on a bool passed in as argument in the constructor?

Tags: c++

I have a class that takes in a boolean called `fixed` as an argument. I want it to initialize the data member `position` as const if `fixed` is true. Is this possible at all?

```
class PhysicsVertex 
{
public:
    PhysicsVertex(olc::vf2d position, const bool fixed = false) :
          position(position), fixed(fixed)
    {
    }
    olc::vf2d position; //make this const if fixed is true.
    const bool fixed = false;
};

int main()
{
    PhysicsVertex v1{ {0, 0}, true }; //initialize v1.position as const
    PhysicsVertex v1{ {0, 0} }; //initialize v1.position as non-const
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your information about `fixed` parameter is needed at compile time then you can use templates

```
#include <type_traits>

struct vf2d
{
};
template <bool fixed>
class PhysicsVertex
{
public:
    PhysicsVertex() :
        position()
    {
    }
    typename std::conditional<fixed, const vf2d, vf2d>::type position;
};

void foo()
{
    auto vertex = PhysicsVertex<true>();
    //  vertex.position = vf2d(); - compile time error, you cannot change const member
    auto vertex2 = PhysicsVertex<false>();
    vertex2.position = vf2d(); // It works fine, you can change non const member
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`const` class members are problematic, because they inhibit a whole bunch of compiler generated methods. For example `PhysicsVertex` cannot be copied. Often the better alternative is to not make it const but instead provide no means to modify it from outside the class:

```
class foo {
    int x = 42; 
public:
    int get() { return x; }
};
```

The member is not modifyable.

Now to your quesiton. You cannot make it `const` or non-`const` based on a runtime value (at least not easily), but following the suggestion above you can conditionally allow to modify it or not:

```
 class foo {
     int x = 42;
     bool modifyable = false;
 public: 
     foo(bool modifyable) : modifyable(modifyable) {}
     void set(int y) {
          if (!modifyable) throw "cannot modify";
          x = y;
     }
  };
```

You should reconsider whether you can already decide to make it `const` or non-`const` at compile time, because then you need not rely on runtime checks and excpetions but can use the approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68393348/4117728).